# Как в Delphi стереть данные таблицы?

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, как в Delphi стереть данные таблицы базы данных?

Comment: Не стесняйтесь указывать СУБД и способ подключения к ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL-запросом

```
TRUNCATE TABLE ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ
```

`Truncate` отрабатывает быстрее и, что может быть немаловажно, сбрасывает счетчик ключевого поля.

Answer (score 2):

Если записей немного (менее 10 тысяч) можно применять и DELETE и TRUNCATE
Если больше настоятельно рекомендую TRUNCATE, а если с DELETE, то удалять надо порциями по несколько тысяч записей с обязательным завершением транзакции (команда COMMIT)

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить SQL:

```
delete from [TableName]
```

или

```
truncate table [TableName]
```